# Tor relay + openvpn to conect from iphone anywhere

Tags: openvpn

I run tor relay ( non exit) and openvpn on the server. I connect to vpn from iphone or any device, but I whant that traffic would go through tor. I am looking for setup instructions

That will allow to use tor network from any device anywhere especially from iphone on 3g or 4g network

Server: Debian jessie

Comment: I believe that *Transparent Proxy* will do this. I've never tried it tho.